# Minimizing an objective function and identify vector values

Tags: r, optimization

I have to minimize the following formula in R:

```
min Z = sum(x_i) * [C * (sum(x_i * B_i)/sum(x_i))]
```

`B_i` and `C` are given constant values and `x` is a vector that needs to be identified.
`x` also has constraints which is dependent on the `i`.

For example:

10 < x1 < 1500

12 < x2 < 1502

...

I have tried using `optim`; however I am having trouble on how to approaching this problem in R. Can anybody give me any ideas to solve this? Thanks.

EDIT: I have tried the following toy function (a minimal reproducible example):

```
f <- function(x){(x[1] + x[2]) * 12 * (50 - (x[1]*10 + x[2]*15)/(x[1]+x[2]))}
p = array( c( 1, 0), dim=c(2,1) )
nlm(f,p)
```

I haven't added the constraints yet as I am not sure how to do so at the moment. But overall, I am guessing there could be a better way to do this. The `x` vector has more than approximately 50 values.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please give a [mre] in your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`optim` with `L-BFGS-B` supports bound constraints:

```
optim(c(1, 0), f, lower = c(10, 12), upper = c(1500, 1502), method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

giving:

```
$par
[1] 10 12

$value
[1] 9840

$counts
function gradient 
       1        1 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```